# Difference between OK and okay?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice, word-difference

should I write :

> [ 1 ] *I am OK*

Or

> [ 2 ]  *I am okay*

Do they differ in meaning or OK is a shortcut of Okay?
When we use OK and okay?

Comment: You should probably write *ok* as *OK* or *O.K.* Other than that, they're exactly the same. Follow this link for more information on their usage and origin: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25617/difference-between-ok-and-okay I don't know why you would even ask this question as this is easily googleable.

Comment: I tend to sense that `OK` is more curt, especially in all caps and/or punctuated, while `okay` is softer.

Answer (score 1):

They are just alternative spellings. You can use either.

The origin of the word is rather unclear. One theory is that it is based off a joke abbreviation of "Oll Korrect".

It is often spelled "okay" or more rarely "okey".

It seems the most common spelling now is "okay". Use that spelling.

(Also "I'm" or "I am" but never "Iam")

Comment: And OK, not ok...